# Knowing if fragment is visible before navigation

Tags: android

I have this code in my Activity:

```
binding.imageViewDot.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragmentApp).navigate(R.id.syncFragment)
        }
 }
```

When clicking the button it navigates to this fragment. But each time the user click it it adds another one. How can I set it to only once. For example, if fragment is visible do not run this code. For example:

```
        binding.imageViewDot.setOnClickListener {
        
        if (//fragment not visible)
            {
                findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragmentApp).navigate(R.id.syncFragment)
            }
        
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `currentDestination` to get the visible `Fragment` and check it's `id` before navigating

```
val navController = findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragmentApp)
if(navController.currentDestination?.getId() != R.id.syncFragment){
    navController.navigate(R.id.syncFragment)
}
```